# PostgreSQL output to JSON object/array

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm running PostgreSQL and are trying to convert this:

```
SELECT car_id AS id, car_model AS model FROM cars
```

into this:

```
[{ "id" : 123, "model" : "Fiat" }, {"id": 124, "model": "BMW"}, ...]
```

I've tried:

```
SELECT json_agg(
           json_build_object(car_id AS id),
           json_build_object(car_model AS model)
       ) FROM cars
```

and a lot other stuff, but seems to be stuck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use only one [json_build_object](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-json.html) in `json_agg` function.

[json_build_object](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-json.html) explain from the document.

> Builds a JSON object out of a variadic argument list. By convention, the argument list consists of alternating keys and values.

using `json_build_object` function parameter will be like

> json_build_object([key1],[Key_Value1],[key2],[Key_Value2]..)

**TestDLL**

```
CREATE TABLE cars(
   car_id INT,
   Car_Model VARCHAR(50)
);

INSERT INTO cars VALUES (1,'TEST1');
INSERT INTO cars VALUES (2,'TEST2');
```

**Query**

```
SELECT json_agg(json_build_object('ID', car_id , 'Model', car_model ))
from cars
```

**Result**

```
|                                                         result |
|----------------------------------------------------------------|
| [{"ID" : 1, "Model" : "TEST1"}, {"ID" : 2, "Model" : "TEST2"}] |
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/f975ab/2)

Comment: Thank you. :) Works, sometimes it's easier than expected.